# How to make Blogger post table scrollable

Tags: html, scroll, blogger

I recently started a [Blogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_%28service%29) blog (*phone specs*). But I just found out that if you click a post, scroll down to the specs table, it doesn't display the features fully on mobile.

I have tried many browsers, but I got the same issue. How can I solve this without making new tables? Is there simple HTML code I can add to the table to make them scrollable?

Site: *phoneprice.xyz*

Comment: check here : https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/#:~:text=Data%20tables%20can%20be%20quite,can't%20get%20any%20narrower.

Comment: Hello, Aman Sharma. Thank you so much for your response. The the major problem is where to add the line of code. Please, do open www.phoneprice.xyz on your browser. Check any post HTML and see how it is. It looks so scattered that I can't figure where to add the code.

Comment: When you create table give the width:100%

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a blog post, there is an option to see it as HTML code in the top right corner.

So, view it as HTML code and add a `style="overflow:scroll"` attribute to the table element.

This should get your problem solved.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your response. The the major problem is where to add the line of code. Please, do open www.phoneprice.xyz on your browser. Check any post HTML and see how it is. It looks so scattered that I can't figure where to add the code.